# Setup hotkeys from command line

Tags: ubuntu, cinnamon

I would like to be able to write scripts that setup my workstation from a blank installation.

My setup is Ubuntu with Cinnamon installed via `apt` (like explained [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/how-to-install-cinnamon-3-0-on-ubuntu))

How do I setup the hotkeys in Cinnamon via the command line that I would otherwise manually setup via `Menu -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts`?

I need to both add and remove some.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you mean Cinnamon as it comes on Linux Mint; and not another application...

The settings are stored in two locations:

```
~/.config/dconf/user
```

and

```
~/.cinnamon
```

Simply backup these folders, and restore them on the 'new' desktop to restore your settings (and then restart X)

You can view the settings using the dconf-editor

Comment: I would rather not have it be all-or-nothing. I just want to change the specific settings I want set.

Comment: Then find them in the config files, make your own config files or export them using dconf-editor, and import those customised ones instead :)

Comment: The config files looks binary. I've attempted to use the dconf-editor to do it, but without getting it to work prior to posting the question.